# how to add lastmod field in index sitemap django

Tags: python, django, xml, web, sitemap

I need to add lastmod attribute to sitemap index.
And it looks like django.contrib.sitemaps.views.index
doesn't include lastmode though
Here is my sitemap.xml:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
<sitemap>
<loc>localhost:8000/sitemap-pages.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

my urls.py

```
sitemaps_pages = {

    'pages': sitemaps.PageViewSitemap,
    'life': sitemaps.LifeViewSitemap,
    'lifes': sitemaps.LifesSitemap,
    'novosti': sitemaps.NewsViewSitemap,
    'novost': sitemaps.NewsSitemap,
    'catalog': sitemaps.CatalogViewSitemap,
    'categories': sitemaps.CategorySitemap,
    'regions': sitemaps.RegionSitemap,
    'times': sitemaps.TimeSitemap,
    'material': sitemaps.MaterialSitemap,
    'products': sitemaps.ProductsSitemap,
}
    path('sitemap-<section>.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps_pages}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    path('sitemap.xml', index, {'sitemaps': sitemaps_pages}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
```

sitemaps.py

```
class ProductsSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    protocol = 'https'
    try:
        priority_filter = strip_tags(Info.objects.get(name='priority_filter').value)
        frequency_filter = strip_tags(Info.objects.get(name='frequency_filter').value)
    except Exception:

        priority_filter = '0.5'
        frequency_filter = 'daily'
    priority = priority_filter
    changefreq = frequency_filter
    limit = 1000

    def items(self):
        return Product.objects.all()

    def location(self, item):
        return str(item.url)

    def lastmod(self, item):
        if item.url == '/':
            return Product.objects.latest('updated_at').updated_at
        else:
            return item.updated_at
```

How do i solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research, and modified generic function index:

```
def index(request, sitemaps, template_name='sitemap_index.xml', content_type='application/xml',sitemap_url_name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'):

    req_protocol = request.scheme
    req_site = get_current_site(request)
    sitemaps_lastmod = []
    sites = []  # all sections' sitemap URLs
    for section, site in sitemaps.items():
        # For each section label, add links of all pages of its sitemap

        if callable(site):
            site = site()
        protocol = req_protocol if site.protocol is None else site.protocol
        sitemap_url = reverse(sitemap_url_name, kwargs={'section': section})
        absolute_url = '%s://%s%s' % (protocol, req_site.domain, sitemap_url)
        sites.append(absolute_url)
        sitemaps_lastmod.append(sitemaps[section].index_lastmod(sitemaps[section]))

        # Add links to all pages of the sitemap.
        for page in range(2, site.paginator.num_pages + 1):
            sites.append('%s?p=%s' % (absolute_url, page))
        if len(sites) > len(sitemaps_lastmod):
            for x in range(len(sites)-len(sitemaps_lastmod)):
                sitemaps_lastmod.append(sitemaps[section].index_lastmod(sitemaps[section]))
    sitez = zip(sites, sitemaps_lastmod)
    return render(request, template_name, {'sitemaps': sitez}, content_type=content_type)
```

and also i copyied sitemap_index.xml file into my templates. Then added to every sitemap class index_lastmod func, that returns last object's updated time
In the sitemap_index.xml I'm iterating through zipped sites locationg and sites lastmod.
sitemap_index.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
{% for location,lastmod in sitemaps %}
    <sitemap>
        <loc>{{ location }}</loc>
        <lastmod>{{ lastmod|date:"Y-m-d" }}</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
{% endfor %}
</sitemapindex>
```

And here i'm checking if sites location more that sites lastmod (cuz of pagination),
then just copy last element's lastmod

```
if len(sites) > len(sitemaps_lastmod):
            for x in range(len(sites)-len(sitemaps_lastmod)):
                sitemaps_lastmod.append(sitemaps[section].index_lastmod(sitemaps[section])
```